# Images do not display on sliders (swiper) when switch direction based on react-intl

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, react-intl

I am using react-intl to change the local language and as one of the languages needs to be 'rtl', I used a solution mentioned in a question.

`dir={intl.locale === 'en-US' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'}`

However, when the direction is switched to 'rtl', images do not display on swiper sliders. is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

just add key prop to your swiper component

```
<Swiper key={intl.locale}></Swiper>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.
If you ever faced such a problem, the only thing to do is to give your swiper
style={{ direction: "ltr" }}

Comment: didn't work for me. I have a nextjs project. I face this problem when switching locale